# Universal links not working when user credentials are auto filled and auto submitted on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

We've discovered that while using universal links to open our app after logging in, that the link will not redirect if the form is auto filled and auto submitted.

The universal link works as expected when the user manually taps the login button after filling out the form.

Does anyone have any insight to whether or not the universal link only triggers with a manual user tap? At this point that is our only theory. Any information on this is much appreciated!

[Here is a link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682213) to a someone that is experiencing the same issue. But still no answers.